# Get javascript-generated html content in Android without Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm trying to get html content of an URL after executing javascript in Android. Because I need the task run silently in background, so Webview is not a good choice. In Java I can use HtmlUnit, but Android I still have no solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks all.